# Basic procedure to use boost with biicode and MSVC 10.0

Tags: c++, boost, biicode

I'd like to test how biicode allows me to quickly create a project that uses boost. I (think I) have followed the procedure outlined in the bii docs.

After modifying the CMakeLists.txt, the configuration step does not succeed. The boost library does not seem to build to be built. I know that sometimes the configure step needs to be done twice (according to http://forum.biicode.com/t/error-could-not-find-the-following-static-boost-libraries-boost-thread/374), but this does not help.

I have pasted the exact steps I took below. I'd be very grateful if someone could show me where I went wrong.

**1. Environnement : Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 10 SP 1**

```
PS G:\> bii --version
3.2
PS G:\> cmake --version
cmake version 3.2.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
PS G:\>
```

**2. Start in a clean folder (G:\biitests)**

**3. Init the bii project**

```
PS G:\biitests> bii init boostUsageTest -L
Successfully initialized biicode project boostUsageTest
```

**4. Create the G:\biitests\boostUsageTest\main.cpp file with the following contents:**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::mutex uselessMutex;
    auto value = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[0]);
    std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**5. bii find**

```
PS G:\biitests\boostUsageTest> bii find
INFO: Processing changes...
WARN: There are local unresolved dependencies
They will not be searched in the server
Unresolved: boost/lexical_cast.hpp
INFO: Finding missing dependencies in server
INFO: Looking for boost/thread...
WARN: Can't find block candidate for: boost/thread
INFO: No block candidates found
```

**6. bii configure**

```
PS G:\biitests\boostUsageTest> bii cpp:configure -G "Visual Studio 10"
INFO: Processing changes...
Running: "cmake"  -G "Visual Studio 10" -Wno-dev  ..\cmake
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
                BLOCK: user/boostUsageTest
-----------------------------------------------------------
+ LIB: user_boostUsageTest
+ EXE: user_boostUsageTest_main
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: G:/biitests/boostUsageTest/bii/build
PS G:\biitests\boostUsageTest>
```

**7. edit CMakeLists.txt in the following way**

(before my changes, the only non-commented line was ADD_BII_TARGETS() )

```
include(biicode/boost/setup)

INIT_BIICODE_BLOCK()

# Create Targets
ADD_BII_TARGETS()

bii_find_boost(COMPONENTS thread REQUIRED)
```

**8. run bii find again**

```
PS G:\biitests\boostUsageTest> bii find --update
INFO: Processing changes...
WARN: There are local unresolved dependencies
They will not be searched in the server
Unresolved: boost/lexical_cast.hpp
INFO: Finding missing dependencies in server
INFO: Looking for biicode/boost...
INFO: Block candidate: biicode/biicode/boost/master
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 9 (DEV) discarded
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 8 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 7 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 6 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 5 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 4 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 3 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 2 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 1 (STABLE) valid
INFO:   Version biicode/boost: 0 (STABLE) valid
INFO: Looking for boost/thread...
WARN: Can't find block candidate for: boost/thread
INFO: Analyzing compatibility for found dependencies...
Find resolved new dependencies:
        biicode/boost: 8
ERROR: Find could not resolve:
        boost/thread/mutex.hpp
INFO: Saving files from: toeb/cmakepp
INFO: Saving files from: biicode/boost
INFO: Saving files from: boost/install
```

**9. Run bii configure again**

```
PS G:\biitests\boostUsageTest> bii cpp:configure -G "Visual Studio 10"
INFO: Processing changes...
Running: "cmake"  -G "Visual Studio 10" -Wno-dev  ..\cmake
                BLOCK: user/boostUsageTest
-----------------------------------------------------------
CALLING INIT_BIICODE_BLOCK IS NO LONGER NECESSARY
+ LIB: user_boostUsageTest
+ EXE: user_boostUsageTest_main
-- No linking type specified. Assuming static linking
-- Setting up biicode Boost configuration...
-- Building Boost 1.57.0 components with toolset msvc-10.0...
Starting thread library build job...
Building Boost components, please wait [                            ]
Finished building thread library
-- Boost version: 1.57.0
CMake Error at ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/core/message.cmake:94 (_message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Boost version: 1.57.0
  Boost include path: G:/Users/bgo/.biicode/boost/1.57.0
  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
          boost_thread
  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message)
  ../deps/toeb/cmakepp/cmake/targets/find_package.cmake:17 (_find_package)
  ../deps/boost/install/install.cmake:351 (find_package)
  ../../CMakeLists.txt:9 (bii_find_boost)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "G:/biitests/boostUsageTest/bii/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ERROR: CMake failed
```

And running bii cpp:configure after that always gives the exact same output.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Benjamin